# How to storage a file into a Database as byte[] with Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I want to storage a file into a database table as `byte[]`. Now I have a question concerning storing a `byte[]` into a `postgres` database table with `Hibernate`. I have this implementation in my `Entity` class:

```
@Column
private byte[] bytes;
```

In my database table it shows the datatype `byte` for the `byte[]`.

Now I can see `plaintext` in this column (in my case the name of the file, which I want to store in the database). For each byte it will repeat the name of the file in the database column. But why?

Is a another Hibernate annotation necessary?

Thanks for help!

Greetz
Marwief

Comment: Generally speaking, putting files into databases is a bad idea.  (IMO, it is only a good idea if you need to write or update the file transactionally)

Answer (score 3):

You must annotate the field with [@Lob](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Lob.html).

Note: If the column is autogenerated, you might think of setting the column definition with an additional annotation (e.g for MYSQL):

```
@Column(columnDefinition="LONGBLOB")//or VARBINARY(128) if you need a smaller limit
```

Comment: @Lob doesn´t work. I get the exception "column is of type bytea but expression is of type bigint"

Comment: Please post the whole stacktrace with the original message. Also you might consider dropping the existing column, if that was autogenerated.

Comment: I must correct my answer! Your Solution works !! Do you have any idea, how many bytes can be storaged, if a column is annotate with lob?

Comment: That depends on the column type in your table/database. Check the specification for that column type for your DB.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
private byte[] bytes;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Domain`

```
    import javax.persistence.Lob;
    @Lob
    private byte[] image;
```

`Repository layer`

```
   byte[] image = getImageAsBytes();
   domain.setImage(image);
   entityManager.save(domain);
```

It should work, atleast it works for us. No special magic